# I can't login to Sitecore CMS anymore

Tags: .net, iis, authentication, sitecore

last week I installed an sitecore 6.4.1 installation on a Server (Win Server 2008, IIS 7, MSSQL 2008).
Suddenly, I can't login to the system. If I try to login with a wrong password, I get an error message. If the data are correct, I see the login-form again without any message.

I already tried to use different browsers, different login-modes and cleared all my cookies in the browser.

The frontend is still working correctly and the license is valid, too.
I have full database access.

Does anybody know an idea, how i can login?

Comment: Can you log in with the admin password? What about requesting a password reset?

Comment: Can you see any errors in Sitecore logs?

Answer (score 4):

I got this error fixed. I changed host name in IIS. Your host name can not contain the underscore(_) chararacter.

Answer (score 2):

If you have database access you can do the following to reset the default admin password:

- Backup the core database (in case this goes horribly wrong)
- In the core, Open the table `dbo.aspnet_Users` table and find the **sitecore\admin** row
- Record the **UserId**
- In the core, open the table `dbo.aspnet_Membership` table and find the row where the **UserId** matches the one you noted from before
- In this row, change the Password value to **qOvF8m8F2IcWMvfOBjJYHmfLABc=**

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have something like this in your web.config

```
<httpCookies domain="#{httpCookiesDomain}" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing"/>
  </system.web>
```

If yes, your web.config not transformed correctly, which is causing the problem.
Correct it to have something like this.

```
<httpCookies domain=".local.com"/>
      </system.web>
```

This resolved my issue.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are logging in OK and just not getting redirected?  ie, after you log in with correct data and don't get an error, just browse to a protected page.

Answer (score 0):

No, when I go to */sitecore/shell/default.aspx?sc_lang=en* I will redirect to */sitecore/login*.
It is the same thing at the admin login (*/sitecore/admin/*).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this my self but with installation with the free xpress version.

In my case I believe the reason was the app couldn't communicate or access with the DB properly. I had installed using default configuration. I believe the DB was sqlite. 
I just installed again with another DB connection option this time using MS sql xpress edition  and I finally manage to login.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen exactly the same problem before - the only thing that fixed it was to **delete everything from C:\Windows\Temp**.

Random I know.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but then remembered that I had changed authentication mode to "Windows" (in Web.config) while testing a web service some weeks ago. Changing it back to "None" helped me pass the login page. Might help someone :-)